# To what extent would the kings of Israel and Judah have been involved in the upbringing and instruction of their children?

Tags: history, melachim-kings-book-of, chinuch-education, biblical-history

To what extent would the kings of Israel and Judah have been involved in the upbringing and instruction of their children? Are there any Biblical references that can help determine this?

Comment: M'lachim I 1:6 indicates that David failed to ever rebuke Adoniya: "וְלֹא עֲצָבוֹ אָבִיו מִיָּמָיו לֵאמֹר מַדּוּעַ כָּכָה עָשִׂיתָ".

Comment: @Fred but it implies that's because of the emotional scars of Avshalom, not that he was normally a totally hands-off parent.

Comment: "Upbringing and instruction" as in 3-year-old, 13-year-old, or 30-year-old? We find that Ahab's grown son is a mayor, so he's clearly being groomed for the job. Uziyahu's son was running the palace day-to-day for many years due to his father's isolation.

Comment: @Shalom with regards to your first comment note Shemos Rabbah 1:1 which states that it was precisely because Dovid did't rebuke Avshalom that he went astray. So there were potentially issues before Adoniya was on the scene?

Comment: Of course if a king had 18 wives and each had a couple of kids, there was only so much he could be around for while still running a country!